# How can I align a minipage of text to a minipage of figure?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, minipage, text

I'm writing a poster so I'm using a two column structure. On the left column I want to have some text side-by-side with a figure. For that I use two minipages that one contains the text and the other - the figure. However, for some reason the text is not aligned with the figure and it goes way down below. Attached is the code and the result. Thanks!

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
$\bullet$ bullet no. 1.\vspace{0.5cm}\\
$\bullet$ bullet no. 2.\vspace{0.5cm}\\
$\bullet$ bullet no. 3.  
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=16cm,height=16cm,keepaspectratio]{bird.png}
\centering\captionof{figure}{\color{Green} A bird}
\label{fig:bird}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Maybe it is possible that it is related to the code before that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: apply a `\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{...}` to the image.

The explanation is that the two `minipage`s are, in fact, aligned to their top baseline (as requested with the `[t]` option of `minipage`).  The problem is that included image extends well above the top baseline, whereas the text does not.  This occurs because `\includegraphics` *always* lays the bottom of its target image on the baseline.  See **ADDNEDUM** for more info.

What I do is move the image down by its height minus the baseline height, so that it ends up hugging the top allowable spot of the baseline text.

In the code below, the image size is changed from the MWE since I have not a poster sized piece of paper.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
$\bullet$ bullet no. 1.\vspace{0.5cm}\\
$\bullet$ bullet no. 2.\vspace{0.5cm}\\
$\bullet$ bullet no. 3.  
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\centering\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{bird.png}}
\captionof{figure}{\color{green} A bird}
\label{fig:bird}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

i would note that one can achieve the same result without the `\raisebox` by placing this at the head of the 2nd `minipage`:  `~\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}`.  This trick places a blank line on the `minipage`, skips to a new paragraph and then backs up one line.  The subsequent image will be forced to lie under the originally introduced blank line.

**ADDENDUM**

As I said to Dudi, "one must first grok that [t] alignment does not mean that the tops of the two respective boxes are aligned. Rather, it means that the baselines of the first row of the two respective `minipages` are aligned."

For a better understanding of `[t]` box alignment, consider this related MWE.  Before executing the OP's code, I `\rlap` a rule on the text baseline.  I also box the `minipage`s so that one can see their extent.  We see in the case of both `minipage`s, the top of the box is above the baseline.  What they share is that the first line of each `minipage` sits on the baseline.  The image in the right-hand `minipage` sits on the baseline because that is the way that `\includegraphics` always does it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\relax
\leavevmode\rlap{\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}Baseline
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
$\bullet$ bullet no. 1.\vspace{0.5cm}\\
$\bullet$ bullet no. 2.\vspace{0.5cm}\\
$\bullet$ bullet no. 3.  
\end{minipage}}%
Baseline
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{bird.png}
\captionof{figure}{\color{green} A bird}
\label{fig:bird}
\end{minipage}}
Baseline
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can now appreciate that the vertical adjustment required on the image will be a downward adjustment of the image height (`-\height`) followed by an upward adjustment of the height of one line of text (`+\ht\strutbox`).

Comment: Great! I'm not sure that I understood your answer, but it solved my problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Dudi glad to help.  One must first grok that `[t]` alignment does not mean that the tops of the two respective boxes are aligned.  Rather, it means that the baselines of the first rows of the two `minipage`s are aligned.  I might add more explanation to my answer.  Stay tuned.

Comment: @Dudi See addendum.